# Where is the last 'GO' statement in Entity Framework code-first script?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Using database-migration in *Entity Framework v6.1.3* code-frist, the generated code doesn't have `GO` before `INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]` statement. Then the `INSERT` statement will be a part of 'a' stored procedure which is not correct.

Where is that `GO`?

```
public partial class _1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.CreateStoredProcedure("a", "select 1");
        this.CreateStoredProcedure("b", "select 2");
    }
}
```

And here is the generated script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [a]
AS
BEGIN
    select 1
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [b]
AS
BEGIN
    select 2
END
-- Where is 'GO' ?!
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId]...
```

Comment: when `BEGIN` and `END` are used, I don't think the INSERT statement will become part of the last procedure. Also the generated script for stored procedure may belong to a totally different round trip (connection) from the one running the INSERT.

Comment: GO is not a T-SQL language construct, anyway. It's an SSMS concept.